# Loop through files and find and replace columns

Tags: excel, vba

I have a VBA script below that loops through files in a folder. I would like to find and replce any "$" with "" (nothing) in columns I and J.

When I run this script it appears to run, but there are no changes within the files. Not too sure where the issue is. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

```
Sub LoopAllExcelFilesInFolder()

Dim wb As Workbook
Dim myPath As String
Dim myFile As String
Dim myExtension As String
Dim FldrPicker As FileDialog

'Optimize Macro Speed
  Application.ScreenUpdating = False
  Application.EnableEvents = False
  Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

'Retrieve Target Folder Path From User
  Set FldrPicker = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)

    With FldrPicker
      .Title = "Select A Target Folder"
      .AllowMultiSelect = False
        If .Show <> -1 Then GoTo NextCode
        myPath = .SelectedItems(1) & "\"
    End With

'In Case of Cancel
NextCode:
  myPath = myPath
  If myPath = "" Then GoTo ResetSettings

'Target File Extension (must include wildcard "*")
  myExtension = "*.xls*"

'Target Path with Ending Extention
  myFile = Dir(myPath & myExtension)

'Loop through each Excel file in folder
  Do While myFile <> ""
    'Set variable equal to opened workbook
      Set wb = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=myPath & myFile)
    
    'Ensure Workbook has opened before moving on to next line of code
      DoEvents
    
    'Find and replace col I and J
       wb.Worksheets(1).Range("I:J").Replace What:="$", Replacement:=""
    
    'Save and Close Workbook
      wb.Close SaveChanges:=True
      
    'Ensure Workbook has closed before moving on to next line of code
      DoEvents

    'Get next file name
      myFile = Dir
  Loop

'Message Box when tasks are completed
  MsgBox "Task Complete!"

ResetSettings:
  'Reset Macro Optimization Settings
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

*Edit - I have found it will work with .xlsx files, but not with .csv. I would need it to work with csv, so any suggestions would be great.

Comment: `myFile = Dir(myPath & myExtension)` will only match on files with extension xlsx, xlsm etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this:

```vb
Sub LoopAllExcelFilesInFolder()

    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim myPath As String
    Dim myFile As String, ext
     
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

    With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
        .Title = "Select A Target Folder"
        .AllowMultiSelect = False
        If .Show = -1 Then myPath = .SelectedItems(1)
    End With
    
    If myPath <> "" Then
        myPath = myPath & "\"
        For Each ext In Array("*.xls*", "*.csv") 'loop different extension patterns
            myFile = Dir(myPath & ext)
            Do While myFile <> ""
                'Debug.Print myFile
                Set wb = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=myPath & myFile)
                wb.Worksheets(1).Range("I:J").Replace _
                   What:="$", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart
                wb.Close SaveChanges:=True
                myFile = Dir()
            Loop
        Next ext
    End If
    
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Note - where possible you should avoid use of `Goto` for flow control.  You only really need `Goto` for handling runtime errors (or maybe for breaking out of nested loops).

Comment: @VBasic2008 - good point. Added.